# Access last value from a SignalProducer when terminated

Tags: reactive-swift

I have a signal producer, when it's terminated I would like to know if a value was sent, I only need the last one, seems so simple ...

```
let myProducer: SignalProducer<MyObject, MyError> = getMyProducer()

myProducer.on(terminated: {

  // I need the last value here

  // Or I need to know if value was never called

}).start()
```

I've tried to store the value in a local var :

```
let myProducer: SignalProducer<MyObject, MyError> = getMyProducer()
var myValue: MyObject?

myProducer.on(value: { value in

    myValue = value

}, terminated: {

    guard let value = myValue else {
        // value was never called
        return
    }
    // value was called

}).start()
```

But sometimes terminated is called while value has been called but myValue is still nil...

Answer (score 1):

First, are you really sure that you want the `terminated` event?

Under normal conditions, an event stream ends with a `completed` event. Exceptions are `failed` when a failure has occurred and `interrupted`, when the observation was ended before the stream could complete normally (E.g. cancellation).

Second: Can your `SignalProducer` fail, and in the failure case, do you still want the last value sent before the failure?

If not, its as easy as using the `take(last:)` operator:

```
enum MyError: Error {
  case testError
}

let (signal, input) = Signal<Int, MyError>.pipe()

let observer = Signal<Int, MyError>.Observer(
  value: { print("value: \($0)") },
  failed: { print("error: \($0)") },
  completed: { print("completed") },
  interrupted: { print("interrupted") }
)


signal
  .take(last: 1)
  .observe(observer)


input.send(value: 1)   // Nothing printed
input.send(value: 2)   // Nothing printed
input.send(value: 3)   // Nothing printed
input.sendCompleted()  // value 3 printed
```

I'm using a `Signal` here so I can manually send events to it just for demonstration, the same works for `SignalProducer` as well.

Note: If we send `interrupted` or a `failed` event, the last value 3 **will not** be sent because those to terminating events short circuit the normal flow.

If your `SignalProducer` can fail, and you still want to get the last value before the failure, you can use `flatMapError` to ignore the Error **before** the `last` operator:

```
signal
  .flatMapError { _ in
    return .empty
  }
  .take(last: 1)
  .observe(observer)
```

Answer (score -1):

my answer :

```
producer
.flatMapError { _ in SignalProducer<Value, NoError>.empty }
.collect()
startWithResult( { result in
  case let .success(results):
    done(with: results.last)
  case let .failure(error):
    () // should not happen as errors are flatmapped
})
```